# Intention of review using spacy in python

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

Can anyone help me how to get intent of product review using spacy with python.Im not getting exact result for all questions

INPUT:   Camera picture quality is good worth for money

OUTPUT:  Camera picture quality

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')         
doc = nlp("Camera picture quality is good worth for money")
for i in doc:
    if i.pos_ in ['ADV','ADJ']:
        for child in i.head.children:
            if child.dep_ == 'nsubj':
                for t in child.children:
                    print(t)
                    print(child)
```

Comment: I think you have to create custom intents for that. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: Its a product review sentence. I need to pick the word which the sentence talks about. In this above example "Camera picture quality is good worth for money". It talks about "Picture quality". For this i need to use 'custom Named Entity Recognizer' ?

Comment: Did you see this from Spacy website? https://github.com/explosion/spacy/blob/master/examples/training/train_intent_parser.py

Comment: This would help -> https://tech.goibibo.com/key-topics-extraction-and-contextual-sentiment-of-users-reviews-20e63c0fd7ca . I worked on a similar project & used spacy.

Comment: oh I need to tag PRODUCT deps in the review? Custom Dependency Parser

Comment: How do you know that the prior knowledge that "product quality" needs to be picked? If there is a corpus/knowledge base that you are referring to, use it to train your custom spacy Named Entity Recognizer.

Comment: @PJay I actually thought of picking 'noun_chunks' FROM DOCUMENT WORD which is dependent to 'nsubj'.   As you say I need to train with Custom Named Entity Recognizer but from @ DhruvPathak and @ Enrique Bruzual it clearly be custom dependency parsing. SO @ PJay which way is better NER or dependency parser. Thanks everyone. I am a beginner so help me

Comment: I'd suggest not to go down the noun chunks route. You'll probably feel a bit lost once you get the results of dependency parsing. Also, if you use spacy for dependency parsing, many a times you won't get accurate results and when you make an algorithm for generalizing the results of dependency parsing you'll see your expectations don't match reality. Hence, go for NER. I build my own custom NERs (I don't use spacy or any other pre-built NER). That way I have more control. If you can, build your own NER, else, start with spacy NER.